# Java client/server socket issues

Tags: java, sockets

I am having some issues connecting a client and server together. The client just times out trying to reach the server.

I have already done the following troubleshooting on my network:

- I have port forwarded the ports correctly (I have done so many many times before) and it still times out.

  - I am using a new modem, a ARRIS TG862 and the first one I got was bad, it would not open the ports at all.
  - Now the ports are opening up correctly because I am hosting a website and people can connect, and also I have hosted a few games and there has been no issues.
- The modem I am using is using IPv6 which I do not know if that is an issue or not?
- I have tried different ports and it still does the same thing. I did even revert to my old modem and router combination and it still will not work.

I am out of options and have no idea what is going on.

- The server/client works fine on localhost but as soon as I try to connect externally it fails.
- When the server is running I can go to canyouseeme.org and it can see the opened port and my program exits because something connected to it.
- I am using the same computer to connect and host, which I have done before and it worked fine a long time ago.
- I also tried using different computers to connect to each other (on the same network).

If there is any suggestions on where to start to determine the cause of my problems that would be great, I am just kind of lost on where to diagnose from here. The code is below. I'll even retry some steps if anyone thinks it is something that I already tested.

#### Client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.EventListener;


public class Client{
    private static Socket socket;
    private static PrintWriter printWriter;
    private int portNumber = 1337;
    private String hostName = "234.123.1.234";//Not real IP, made up ip address to demonstrate code to stack overflow users


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Client().validateSecurity();
    }

    public void validateSecurity(String key){
        try {
            Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

#### Server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.net.ServerSocket; 
import java.net.Socket; 
import java.net.UnknownHostException; 
import java.util.EventListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Server{
    private static Socket socket;
    private static PrintWriter printWriter;
    private int portNumber = 1337;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Server().validateSecurity("hi");
    }

    public void validateSecurity(String key){
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            System.out.println("WAITING ON CONNECTION");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("CONNECTION ACCEPTED");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of Server are you connecting to? mySQL, SQL Server xxxx or Oracle?

Comment: Your `main` method inside your `client` runs a `new Server()` ... should that be a `new Client()`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was just copying code over from a history that was changed awhile back. It was a simplified version and I guess i didnt go far enough back :P.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct any copy/paste mistakes.  Make sure your question _exactly_ represents the real code on your machine, otherwise it will waste other people's time chasing the wrong issue.

Comment: It's definitely not a problem with the code above (with line 19 of the client corrected). Triple check your network configuration.

Comment: Try connecting with Port: 8080, or 80, or 1024. And make sure that both servers are running.

Comment: In java 8, sandboxed applets can't use sockets.

Comment: What does that mean? That I cannot run 2 sockets in the same virtual machine? Can you explain that a little further? Also I am going to try the other ports and see what happens. Ill also check my network configuration one more time. Will update once I do so.

Comment: ok then to confirm that you dont have the issue you mentioned , can you try simply ping the ip to see that is responding

Comment: I pinged my ipaddress with that port via http://ping.eu/port-chk/ and via http://www.canyouseeme.org/. Both of them connected and told me the port is opened. And even ran on my server side. Is this because of what ddyer said 12 minutes ago? I dont really understand what he means tho.

Comment: Also ran via 8080 and 1024 and still getting the same issue. Connection timed out: connect. And I checked network configuration and everything is perfect........SecurityValidator TCP/UDP 63400 63400 192.168.1.5 <<<<< in modem (Modem is both modem and router) and ipconfig shows 192.168.1.5 for local ip

Comment: Whats the differences between Socket(InetAddress address, int port) and Socket(String hostname, int port)? I am using hostname but for the hostname I am using my external ip address. Could this be the issue? Should I be using InetAddress?

Comment: For some reason my modem is still giving off a IPV6 ipaddress, when I put google whats my ip I get a IPV6 address like this 2222:a:2222:22:e22e:eee2:eeee:e222. I put that in the connection and it worked fine. Anyone know what is up with that? I can click on a link and it give me my IPV4 ipaddress but I cannot connect with it.

Answer (score 0):

A connection timeout almost always indicates a firewall problem.

Comment: The issue appears to be the IPV6 address, I can go to ping websites like canyouseeme.org and ping the IPV4 address but as soon as I use the IPV4 address in the java code it will not connect and will time out. But if I use the IPV6 address in the code it works perfectly. Anyone know why this is? How do I know I am coding for IPV6 instead of IPV4?